# How can I modify the page number for abstract in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, abstract

I am very new in LaTeX. I am writing a thesis and I need to have two abstracts one in English and one in Portuguese. However, when I try to include them in this way:

```
\selectlanguage{portuguese}
\begin{abstract}
    Abstract in Portuguese
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
    Abstract in English
\end{abstract}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Resumo}%
\newpage\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}%
\newpage\clearpage
\tableofcontents
```

in the table of contents they appear to be on the same page:
[image]

I would be very grateful if you could help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) on this site it is always a good idea to post full minimal examples, i.e. documents that others can copy and compile on their own systems. This makes it a lot easier to help. In your case isn't the two abstracts on the same page anyway?

Comment: Plus `\addcontentsline` does not add anything to the output so `\newpage\clearpage\newpage\clearpage` is the same as `\newpage\clearpage`. Might be an idea to be a bit more clear about what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the `xpatch` package and the `\xapptocmd` macro to automatically append the `\addcontentsline` for the abstract to the ToC as section entry (`\abstractname` defined by correct language by `\selectlanguage` and `babel`) as well as appending `\clearpage` to `\endabstract` (the end code macro of the abstract environment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{portuguese}
\xapptocmd{\abstract}{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\abstractname}}{}{}%
\xapptocmd{\endabstract}{\clearpage}{}{}
\begin{abstract}
    Abstract in Portuguese
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
    Abstract in English
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage    
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should put `\clearpage` where is needed, not between `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{portuguese}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Resumo}%
\begin{abstract}
    Abstract in Portuguese
\end{abstract}

\clearpage

\selectlanguage{english}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}%
\begin{abstract}
    Abstract in English
\end{abstract}

\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it compiles fine on Arch Linux with the latest TeXlive.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works :) I wish I could up-vote you..

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You refer to the previous code. After noticing that I switched to `memoir` class.

Comment: @Astrinus: Ah, I see you changed in the meantime. I will delete my comment

Answer (score 0):

Set the page counter inside your abstract to the page number you desire

```
\begin{abstract}

    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{5}

    This is the starting of abstract text.

\end{abstract}
```